# Unable to load populator class "LifecycleListPopulator"

Tags: wso2

I create a WSO2 Governance artifact and i tried to add it an input to display a list of the existing lifecycles:

```
<field type="options">
 <name label="Lifecycle Name">Lifecycle Name</name>
   <values 
     class="org.wso2.carbon.governance.services.ui.utils.LifecycleListPopulator">   
   </values>
 </field>
```

i also tried whit the class:"org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.LifecycleListPopulator"

The system logs show:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.utils.GenericUIGenerator} - Unable to   
load populator class
```

Does the class who populate the lifecycles list has changed ??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there have been some changes in the locations please try to use the following

"org.wso2.carbon.governance.generic.ui.utils.LifecycleListPopulator"

Regards